# Python match string with dynamic number in string

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string and want to match which has words, number, and forward slash.
for eg my string is 'abc/11/xyz'
I tried it but returns nothing,

```
re.match(r'(a-z)+/(\d)+/(\w)+', 'abc/11/xyz')
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
re.match(r'([a-z])+/(\d)+/(\w)+', 'abc/11/xyz')
```

`(a-z)+` matches literally `a-z`. It seems you want to match any characters between a and z, so you need to use square brackets `([a-z])+` to make a character class.

Comment: If this really be the only problem with the OP, then I might say it is a typo, in which case we should just vote to close.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is not a typo, it is lack of regex knowledge.